# Unable To Open Files On New Intranet Site

Tags: php, apache, iis-7, permissions

I have recently switched a PHP based intranet site from an Apache server to a server running IIS7.  I have installed PHP to the server and everything (as far as I can tell) is working properly with one exception.

On the site are many links to .pdf and .doc files that are located on another server.  On my Apache server everything worked fine for the users (left click and file opened).  On the new IIS7 server nothing happens when the user left clicks; however, the file can be downloaded by right clicking and "save target as...".

I am very new at IIS7 so any help would be appreciated.  (Also this is my first question.  Big fan of the site.)

Comment: why would any one move from  Apache  to  IIS7 ?

Comment: It definitely wasn't my decision, that's for sure.

Comment: Does the browser actually send a request when you left click?

Comment: Was it on Linux based system for Apache?

Comment: @E_p: It was running on a Windows based system.

Comment: @StevenVondruska: Yes it is sending requests.

Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adjusting the "Trusted Sites" on the workstations that were looking to access the files.

Moral of the story: Start with the simplest solutions and work your way up.

Thank you to all who commented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mime type issue most likely.

In IIS go to MIME types and add the proper extensions.

or you can do it in the webconfig:

```
<system.webServer>

<staticContent>

<mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf"/>

<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>

<mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>

<mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"/>
...
</staticContent>
```

Comment: This is what I thought as well; however, the MIME types have been set up properly to work with .pdf, .doc and .docx.

Thank you for your reply!